# Jquery InputMask dynamic validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-inputmask

Possible to make the input mask to enter both digit and character 'x' , but the input only accept a single 'x' regardless of the position.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/bindings/inputmask.binding.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-inputmask-mask="9999">
```

This is what I currently working on , just wonder if input mask can do what I need , and else I have to use other way round.

Below is the scenario I wanted to achieve , the format must be in 4 character.

```
11x1
1x11
232x
x982
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxb2np75/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id='word' maxlength="4">

$('#word').keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).val().length==3 && $(this).val().includes('x'))
    $(this).val($(this).val()+'x')  
})
```

**Test cases**

- At least one letter should be 'x'
- First 3 string may be letters, so last letter should be 'x'
- If first 3 string contains x, no issue

Update it if you want to allow only *'numbers' and 'x'*